# Only static members can be acessed in initializers (passing a list as a argument in flutter inside a stateful widget)

Tags: flutter

I'm having problems passing a list as an argument in flutter:

```
class Question {
  String p;
  int r;
  List<String> r2;
 

  Question({this.p, this.r, this.r2});
}

List<String> perguntas = ['pergunta1', 'pergunta2', 'pergunta3', 'pergunta4'];

  List<String> respostas = ['resposta1', 'resposta2', 'resposta3', 'resposta4'];
  Question q1 = Question(p: perguntas[0], r: 1, r2: respostas);
```

i alwyas get the error Only static members can be acessed in initializer.

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: i alwyas get the error Only static members can be acessed in initializers.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
class Question {
  String p;
  int r;
  List<String> r2;
 

  Question({this.p, this.r, this.r2});
}

void main() {
  List<String> perguntas = ['pergunta1', 'pergunta2', 'pergunta3', 'pergunta4'];

  List<String> respostas = ['resposta1', 'resposta2', 'resposta3', 'resposta4'];
  Question q1 = Question(p: perguntas[0], r: 1, r2: respostas);

  print(q1.r2.toString());
}
```

Output:

```
[resposta1, resposta2, resposta3, resposta4]
```

Comment: well not for me i get the "Only static members can be accessed in initializers". error

Comment: i just realized thats because i am running this inside a stateful widget

Comment: Glad I could help.